# How do I access double pointer from C code in ASM's stack

Tags: c, assembly, x86-16, dos

I have a `main.c` function which has the following statement:

```
int  initarr(int**arr, int n, int (*initfunc)(int));
```

Then I call the function in `c` like that:

```
success = initarr(&arr, n, getNum);
```

The question is, in assembly code, in `MODEL SMALL`, the first argument in the function above will be in the memory as `WORD` or `DWORD`?

In other words, when I write the code, will this work:

```
PUSH BP
MOV BP,SP

PUSH DI
MOV DI, WORD PTR[BP+4] ; DI will hold &arr.
```

And now `DI` will hold arr's address.

**If it is true, How will I be able to access arr[0]'s value if so?**

```
PUSH BP
MOV BP,SP

PUSH DI
PUSH BX
MOV DI, WORD PTR[BP+4]
MOV BX, WORD PTR[DI]
```

Will BX hold the address of the array? I mean, the address of the first cell?

If so, how can I access arr[0] now?

Perhaps `MOV DX, WORD PTR[BX]` ?

Comment: Write it in C, compile it and look with the debugger what is generated.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie This is brilliant idea. I'll check this out when I come home and update!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **model small**, addresses are sized 2 bytes. A double pointer is still an address!

in order to access arr[0], you would write the following:

```
MOV DI, [BP+4]  ; no need casting, DI register is sized 2 bytes.
MOV SI, [DI]    ; get what DI is pointing to, and put it to SI. 
                ; you could say: DI=arr[][], SI = arr[]
MOV AX, [SI]    ; now AX = arr[0]
```

if we would like to access arr[i], we would do the following:

```
MOV DI, [BP+4]  
MOV SI, [DI]     
MOV AX, i
SHL AX, 1   ; because arr[] contains int numbers which are sized 2 bytes.
ADD SI, AX
MOV AX, [SI]    ; now AX = arr[i].  SI = &arr[i].
```