# Can't convert code from C to ASM (Undefined symbol)

Tags: c, assembly, x86-16, dos

I'm trying to convert the code below from C to ASM because I'm having a tiny difficulty writing a procedure in ASM.

in DDOSBox the command I use: `tcc -v -S -r- main.c`

**I'm getting an error:** Undefined symbol _initarr in module main.c

Code: [`main.c`]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern int initarr(int** arr, int n,  int (*initfunc)(int));
int getNum(int idx);

int getNum(int idx) { 
return (4*idx);
}

void main()  {
int *arr, i, n, success;
printf("\nPlease enter the array size\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
success = initarr(&arr, n, getNum);   
    if(!success) {
        printf("Memory Allocation Failed\n");
        return;
    } 
printf("\nThe Numbers in the allocated array are:\n");
for(i=0; i<n; i++)   
    printf("%d  ", arr[i]);
return;
}
```

Comment: I'm doing this to study how to access double pointer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365841/how-do-i-access-double-pointer-from-c-code-in-asms-stack

Comment: OK, well, where is initarr?

Comment: @MartinJames Yes my bad, I solved it now :)

Comment: @MartinJames How can I initialize the array by calling the function getNum? because I don't understand how to use a pointer to function getNum which will initialize arr[i]'s values.